# Spring Integration create asynchronous thread in service activator method

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-integration

I am writing a cache service using Spring Integration over TCP. I have a method in service class which gets called using service-activator and returns the value from the cache. I need to create an asynchronous thread in this method in case of a cache miss to load the data asynchronously while the calling service-activator thread should return immediately with a null value. The service java method code is as follows.

```
    public Object getValue(Object key){
        Object valueObj = cache.get(key);
        if(null == valueObj) {
            taskExecutor.execute(new AsyncDataLoader(key));
        }
        return valueObj;
    }

    private class AsyncDataLoader implements Runnable{
        private Object key;
        public AsyncDataLoader(Object key){
            this.key = key;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Object valueObj = dataClient.getData(key);
                put(key, valueObj);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Spring integration part:

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="inputObjChannel"
    ref="myService" method="getValue" />
```

But instead of service-activator calling thread returning immediately, it waits for the AsyncDataLoader to complete. Is there any way I can achieve asynchronous data loading?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by

> it waits for the AsyncDataLoader to complete

Returning `null` effectively stops the integration flow - when a service returns no result, all messaging stops; the thread will return to whatever started it; if that's a gateway, it will wait there forever waiting for a result that will never arrive (unless the gateway has a timeout).

You will need to return some value that indicates a cache miss instead.

Comment: By sending a non-null response helped resolved this issue. Thanks for the suggestion.